# modrewrite issue - 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this url

```
http://sites.com/driver.php?n=spa
```

I made it look like this

```
http://sites.com/driver/spa
```

here is .htaccess code I am using..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^driver([^/]*)$ driver.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it's working but for instance all my files including scripts and stylesheets are not working because it's adding to /driver to all urls
like this example

```
http://sites.com/style.css
```

to

```
http://sites.com/driver/style.css
```

.. I can avoid by writing the full script and stylesheet urls but is there any other way? I can do this but I have more than 40 script and stylesheet urls and it will take me time to rewrite them all with the full url.

Comment: Add this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thank you a ton.. post it as answer so I can accept it.. made my project easy, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of this problem is use of relative links on CSS/js/image resources. To fix this issue you can sdd this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

This week tell browser's to append a / everyone it finds a relative path resource in the page.