# How to change form url parameter on submit?

Tags: javascript, url

I have this form for processing..

```
<form action="driver.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="n">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

by default the url is `http://sites.com/driver.php?n=typedname`

so i did modifications in .htaccess and convert it to `http://sites.com/driver/typedname` for SEO friendly urls [modrewrite issue - 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280890/modrewrite-issue-404-error) thanks to anubhava

everything is well, but the problem now comes when I type and click the submit button, it will go to `http://sites.com/driver.php?n=typedname`

so how can I make it to go this url `http://sites.com/driver/typedname` instead after clicking submit?

I think javascript can do this, so i tagged it, hope im not wrong.

thanks.

Comment: I am confused with what you are trying to do exactly? You're trying to go this new page after submit? Change your action URL?

Comment: so now whether you type it http://sites.com/driver/typedname or http://sites.com/driver.php?n=typedname it works ?

Comment: No, this is nothing that javascript should do. Instead, make your webserver transparently redirect clients to the url with the slash.

Comment: cport I don't mean exactly to go to that url, I have just used it as an example.. it all depends what the user inputs. so whatever the user inputs and he/she clicks submit, I want it to go http://sites.com/driver/userinput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### jQuery

```
$('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    window.location = "http://sites.com/driver/" + $('#search').val();

    return false;
});
```

or

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { // you really need to class/ID your form
    // all that code
});
```

Now this is quick and dirty to give you the idea. You'd of course want to sanitize your input (good idea to do that on the front-end as well as the back-end).

Comment: What if the form is submitted by pressing enter in the input?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to handle form submit event yourself. Something like this:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = '/driver/' + this.elements.n.value;
}, false);
```

Comment: dfsq that worked perfectly.  i just specified the form with an id so it doesn't send every form on the page to the same place.  & changed the location and value and it worked beautifully.  now i don't have to use a slow & sloppy redirect on my ajax live search just to keep my website uniform with all mod_rewrite pretty link locations.  awesome.